# For PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile which UI Designer Tool to use?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have currently found the following. What are your recommendations? I am really looking for drag n drop UI/UX designer tool which also uses JQueryMobile widgets and the remaining application logic I will code in Eclipse.

- Dreamweaver CS6
- Tiggzi
- Just in mind
- Codiqa

Comment: What development platform are you using? Windows, Mac...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XDK AppFramework from Intel, and Codiqa is quite nice